# Using in and or together always true in python

Tags: python

```
w = ""

if "who" in w or "what" in w :
    print("ok")
```

the above code always results true and prints ok.

Comment: As @MatsLindh says, the code you present could not give the result you report. Did you perhaps really code `if "who" or "what" in w :`? That *would* give the result you report. Always present the *exact* code that is giving the trouble, not an edited or redacted or retyped version.

Comment: My code editor went mad

Answer (score 3):

There must be something else going on than what you have in your question, since your assumption isn't true:

```
>>> w = ""
>>>
>>> if "who" in w or "what" in w :
...     print("ok")
...
<prints nothing>
>>> "who" in w or "what" in w
False
```

Comment: Sorry after I restarted my computer the issue was over